# Conical cylinders, or cylindrical cones?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> My head you can plane, it's has cylinders for cones
>   My heart controls a set that almost everyone owns
>   My tail is a feeling with a land devoted to it
>   When I'm done with a house, the owner ain't left with .. much.

Who or what am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hope this attempt is warm

> Fire

My head you can plane, it has cylinders for cones

> Fir - [Flight information region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_information_region), and [conifer cones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conifer_cone) which may be more cylinder-shaped.

My heart controls a set that almost everyone owns

> IR - the main technology used in home remote controls for TV sets is infrared (IR) light.

My tail is a feeling with a land devoted to it

> ire - anger and has Ireland devoted to it!

When I'm done with a house, the owner ain't left with .. much.

> Fire - burning down the house.

Comment: Oh, you managed to fit *that* kind of planes in too, very nice! I was thinking about carpentry myself. Well that, and how those particular  cones are typically cylinders standing upright, which kind of seemed to fit in nicely with the idea of planes.

Comment: Shapely, smooth and solid geometrical imagery! Your explanation is planer and I wood knot have got it :)

Comment: @Tom Yew saw what he did there.

Comment: Ni*ce dar*e to *firs*t spruce up this post on *Jun 1 per*haps.